# Xpath to verify multiple TD to filter 1 unique TR

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver, robotframework

I need to verify that a `<tr>` exists which contains 3 `<td>` with specific values.

There are 100+ `<tr>` tags on the page. I am trying to filter them using 1 xpath.

for instance if I filter all the `<tr>` on these 3 values:

`//td[contains(text(),'Belgium')]`

`//td[contains(text(),'be-stelara-cd-uc')]`

`//td[contains(text(),'2022-07')]`

That should return 1 `<tr>` containing those `<td>`.

So what I need to do, would be to filter each xpath against the previous leaving a single unique  remaining. I came across the `|` union operator which is almost what I want but instead of combining the results I want to exclude them.

I tried this xpath:

`//tr[contains(td/text(), 'Belgium') and contains(td/text(), 'be-stelara-cd-uc') and contains(td/text(), '2022-07')]`

html example:

https://prnt.sc/qcmEu0zSvu3S

Edit:

`//tr[contains(td/text(), 'Belgium') and contains(td[2]/text(), 'be-stelara-cd-uc') and contains(td[3]/text(), '2022-07')]`

This works, I did not realise that the td would check for ordering as well. If possible I would like to tweak the question to come up with a universal solution considering that the order cannot be guaranteed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can rely on the data in the picture, that is: no whitespace and no other inline-elements more than shown, you could try this:

```
//tr[td[text()= 'Belgium'] and td[text()= 'be-stelara-cd-uc'] and td[contains(text(), '2022-07')]]
```

If you want to be extra sure and want to filter unwanted space you could try this:

```
//tr[td[text()[normalize-space()= 'Belgium']] and td[text()[normalize-space()= 'be-stelara-cd-uc']] and td[contains(text(), '2022-07')]]
```

If more content can be present just use the `.` and `contains()` together like this:

```
//tr[td[contains(., 'Belgium')]and td[contains(., 'be-stelara-cd-uc')]and td[contains(., '2022-07')]]
```

And to be complete you could also just test the text-content of the tr like this:

```
//tr[contains(., 'Belgium') and contains(., 'be-stelara-cd-uc') and contains(., '2022-07')]
```

Comment: Option 1 feels the most natural to use in this case but I don't understand why you use a contains for the 2022-07 string but not for the others. Maybe that is because I don't understand the difference between `td[contains(text(), '2022-07')]` and `td[contains(., '2022-07')]`. Could you use contains instead of text()= for all 3 options instead of just the final one?

Comment: In your example there is no td that = 22-07, therefore I we use contains

Comment: Of course you can use contains, but it is better and faster if you know the content equals some text to use text()=

Answer (score 0):

Use any of the below `xpath` to identify the `tr`

```
//tr[.//td[contains(., 'Belgium')]][.//td[contains(., 'be-stelara-cd-uc')]][.//td[contains(., '2022-07')]]
```

OR

```
//tr[contains(., 'Belgium') and contains(., 'be-stelara-cd-uc') and contains(., '2022-07')]
```

Comment: Could you give some explanation as to how these xpath's work? I prefer to not just copy paste a solution.

Comment: 1st xpath checking row which contains columns and specific text as well. 2nd xpath checking rows which contains specific text in the row. Hope you got that.